# How can i rearrange the contents within a string? Java

Tags: java

I was wondering how I can rearrange the contents within a string. For example,
if it was `String s = "Stack,over,flow";` How can I change the position of flow with stack or stack with over?

Comment: Just understand that it won't be the same String, it's a new one. String is immutable in Java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is not built-in support, the most obvious solution i think is:

```
String s = "Stack,over,flow";
String[] arr = s.split(",");
// now you have all the parts in arr, you can reconstrut your new string here.
```

Comment: I'd write a swap method (since Java doesn't have one built in). Something like:

 public void arraySwap(Object[] arr1, int pos1, int pos2) {
  Object tmp = arr1[pos1];
  arr1[pos1] = arr1[pos2];
  arr1[pos2] = tmp;
 }

Comment: yes, i know the split method, but how can I change the position within the string. How can I change the position with the same string?

Comment: see @duffymo 's answer below: **string is immutalbe**.

Comment: As a previous stackoverflow post (http://goo.gl/K0RHY) points out, the Collections framework does have a swap method. Maybe you could convert your arrays to Lists and use the swap method? Apache commons collections could also be useful for you List manipulation etc.